# Cycling values in divs on button click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to add new values to the `#current` element every time the button is clicked. The `#current` element then passes that value to the previous divs.

However, the problem I have here is that I am getting values and it's getting passed around to the previous divs but the value on `#current` isn't changing and stays the same until the cycle is finished.

I want `#current` element to get new value every time the button is clicked and that new value keeps passing around to the `prev` divs.

```
// Click-1:
value out:
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
new value every click: 1234

// Click-2:
value out:
1:
2:
3:
4:
5: 1234
new value every click: 2255

// Click-3:
value out:
1:
2:
3:
4: 1234
5: 2255
new value every click: 3245

// Click-4:
value out:
1:
2:
3: 1234
4: 2255
5: 3245
new value every click: 1413
```

This is the code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $target = $('div.active');
  if (!$target.length) {
    $('#current').text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $target.removeClass('active');
    $target.prev('div').addClass('active').text($target.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="out">value out:</div>
<div id="1">1: </div>
<div id="2">2: </div>
<div id="3">3: </div>
<div id="4">4: </div>
<div id="5">5: </div>
<div id="current">new value every click:</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/a26s5oxg/2/

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop through each `div` and set its text to the match that the following `div`. If there is no following `div`, then you know you're at the end of the set and need to instead generate a new random number. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.container div span').each(function() {
    $(this).text(function() {
      var $target = $(this).parent().next('div').find('span');      
      return $target.length ? $target.text() : Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button><br/><br/>

<div class="container">
  <div id="out">value out: <span></span></div>
  <div id="1">1: <span></span></div>
  <div id="2">2: <span></span></div>
  <div id="3">3: <span></span></div>
  <div id="4">4: <span></span></div>
  <div id="5">5: <span></span></div>
  <div id="current">new value every click: <span></span></div>
</div>
```

Note the addition of `<span />` elements to the HTML in order to make setting the values easier. If you didn't do this you'd have to go digging through text nodes which is an unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo very much @Rory for the answer. It resolved the issue for me as intended. Also, thank you for the explanation to help understand the solution better. Thank you once again and have a brilliant day :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help